# Private Constructor Object initialization

Tags: java

I read the following code on NULL object pattern but there is one thing that I am really not clear on. The code follows.

```
//Null.java
package test_package1;

public interface Null {

}

//Person.java
class Person {
    public final String first;
    public final String last;
    public final String address;
    // etc.
    public Person(String first, String last, String address){
        this.first = first;
        this.last = last;
        this.address = address;
    }
    public String toString() {
        return "Person: " + first + " " + last + " " + address;
    }
    public static class NullPerson
    extends Person implements Null {
        private NullPerson() { super("None", "None", "None"); }
        public String toString() { return "NullPerson"; }
    }
    public static final Person NULL = new NullPerson();
}
```

Now, I've a question: why should the following code snippet work:

```
public static final Person NULL = new NullPerson();
```

The NullPerson class has a private constructor, so how is the object instantiation possible outside the class scope?

Secondly, what is the need of making the NullPerson class as a static inner class?

Comment: `but since the code is so small, I really hope that you will not mind the inconvenience.` It's easier for your to indent it, then for us to _not mind_. Use your IDE.

Comment: -1 for the comment... since the code is so small, sure you can format it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An enclosing type has access to any member (and that member's members) declared (nested) within it, regardless of its declared access modifiers.

> Secondly, what is the need of making the NullPerson class as a static inner class?

To make what they did possible. In my opinion, the type itself should be `private`. No other types can do anything with `NullPerson`.

Comment: "the type itself should be private" Could you clarify it more?

Comment: @pulp_fiction `NullPerson` is declared as `public`. That means any other type can see it and use it, even though they can't use its constructor. Since there's nothing else of use in `NullPerson`, there's no point for it to be visible to other types. It should be `private`.

Comment: Yeah, there really is no point in exposing it, because you can't really use it. I too can't think of any scenario where it should be made public.